# Python Data Merge: Creating a New Table with Sample IDs and Replicate Counts

Tags: python-3.x, data-wrangling

I want to merge two tables using Python. One table contains measurement series, while the other table contains additional information such as the number of measurement repetitions and sample name.

df2:

| Replicates | Sample Name | Sample ID | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | aplha_123 | A |  |  |
| 3 | aplha_456 | B |  |  |

df1:

| Sample Name | Time | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | ... | B1 | B1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aplha_123 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| aplha_456 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I want to generate a table that inserts an additional column on the left. The column name should be 'Sample Name + Sample ID' with a consecutive number. The value should be the sample name plus the number of replicates.

[image: result table]

I tried the following code but it does not work porperly

```
for column in df1.columns:
    if re.match(r'[A-Za-z]\d', column): 
        letter = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]', column)[0]  
        replicate_count = df2.loc[df2['Sample ID'] == letter, 'Replicates'].values[0]  
        new_column_name = f'sample name {column}'
        if not pd.isnull(replicate_count):
            sample_name = df2.loc[df2['Sample ID'] == letter, 'Sample Name'].values[0] 
            for i in range(1, int(replicate_count) + 1):
                adjusted_index = i
                new_column_value = f'{sample_name} #{adjusted_index}'
                if new_column_name not in df1.columns:
                       df1.insert(df1.columns.get_loc(column), new_column_name, new_column_value)
```

Comment: The logic is not fully clear, please provide the exact expected output given the provided inputs, and remove the `...` from the input (keep it minimal)